# Laravel resource route being assigned incorrect parameter name

Tags: php, laravel

Using Laravel 5.6, I'm generating a resource controller with the following command:

```
php artisan make:controller SkusController --resource --model=Sku
```

The generated controller file has correctly type-hinted methods. For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Sku;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class SkusController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Sku  $sku
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Sku $sku)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Now, I add a resource route to my routes file, like this:

```
Route::resource('skus', 'SkusController');
```

However, in my routes list, the named parameter in these routes is appearing as `skus`, not `sku`, causing the route-model binding not to work. The `$sku` variable in the controller methods turns out empty.

For example, here's the URI for the `show` methods entry in the `php artisan route:list` output:

```
skus/{skus}
```

Alternatively, I followed the same process for a `products` resource, and the URI is correct:

```
products/{product}
```

In that case the route-model binding works as expected since the controller variable is called `$product`.

I think I can [manually change the parameter name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters), but I'm just wondering why that should be necessary. Shouldn't the route be generated correctly in the first place?

Comment: I get exactly the same results. The command automatically injects `$sku`, which doesn't work but renaming it to `$skus` works. Seems like a bug.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get it working with `Route::resource('skus', 'SkusController')->parameters(['skus' => 'sku']);`, but I'll still report it as an issue on Github.

Comment: Laravel uses the Doctrine [Inflector](https://github.com/doctrine/inflector/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Inflector/Inflector.php) for pluralization, you can file issues against that for unintended results.

Comment: @sam yea looks like that's the issue: `Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector::singularize('skus');` outputs 'skus' instead of 'sku'.

Comment: Laravel always recommends using `singular` model names for `Route::resource`, and it will handle the pluralization automagically for you

Comment: To add to @Ohgodwhy's good advice, in a convention-over-configuration framework like Laravel or Rails knowing and following the convention is the key to getting stuff done and not fighting the framework.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Is that true though? Let alone that having resources prefixed with the plural version seems more intuitive and more common in APIs, [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers) also seems to use pluralized prefixes most of the time.

Comment: Agree with you @devk, I'm not sure this is really a convention-over-configuration situation. I've seen countless examples of using plural resource names for api routes. This is simply a bug with the Inflector class not 'singularizing' the word correctly.

Answer (score 16):

You can use it like:

```
Route::resource('skus', 'SkusController')->parameters(['skus' => 'sku']);
```

It can be used in Route model binding. like

```
public function update(Request $request, Sku $sku)
    {
        $sku->update(); // data to be updated
    }
```

where Sku will be your Model name.

Comment: There is also this syntax: `Route::resource('skus', 'SkusController')->parameter('skus', 'sku');` slightly shorter.